# Google Video no longer able to retrieve captions?

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-data-api

As of 4 days ago, you were able to send a GET request to or visit [https://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=en&v={youtubeVideoId}](https://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=en&v=%7ByoutubeVideoId%7D) and receive an xml response containing the caption track of a given youtube video. Does anyone know if this support has been removed, because as of tonight, it no longer provides the xml response with the captions, the page is simply empty for every video. There were numerous videos this worked for 4 days ago that no longer work. Thanks in advance

Comment: see related (but old) issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/170235670

Comment: Let me add that this did not require access to the API whatsoever; no API key needed, the site at the URL was the xml file regardless of how you accessed it

Comment: See this issue on Google tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/207527674

Comment: why do sites like youglish still work? How did they get captions from youtube videos?

Answer (score 12):

**Captions in default language (single available or English it seems):**

To get captions of a YouTube video just use this Linux command (using curl and base64):

```bash
curl -s 'https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/get_transcript?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw "{\"context\":{\"client\":{\"clientName\":\"WEB\",\"clientVersion\":\"2.9999099\"}},\"params\":\"$(printf '\n\x0bVIDEO_ID' | base64)\"}"
```

Change the `VIDEO_ID` parameter with the one interesting you.

Note: the key isn't a YouTube Data API v3 one, it is the first public (tested on some computers in different countries) one coming if you `curl https://www.youtube.com/ | grep AIzaSy`

Note: If interested in how I reverse-engineered this YouTube feature, say it in the comments and I would write a paragraph to explain

**Captions in desired language if available:**

YouTube made things tricky maybe to lose you at this step, so follow me: the only thing we have to change is the `params` value which is base64 encoded data which is in addition to weird characters also containing base64 data which also contains weird characters.

1. Get the language initials like `ru` for russian
2. Encode `\n\x00\x12\x02LANGUAGE_INITIALS\x1a\x00` in base64 with for instance `A=$(printf '\n\x00\x12\x02LANGUAGE_INITIALS\x1a\x00' | base64)` (don't forget to change `LANGUAGE_INITIALS` to your language initials wanted `ru` for instance). The result for `ru` is `CgASAnJ1GgA=`
3. Encode the result as a URL by replacing the `=` to `%3D` with for instance `B=$(printf %s $A | jq -sRr @uri)`. The result for `ru` is `CgASAnJ1GgA%3D`
4. *Only if using shell commands:* replace the single `%` to two `%` with for instance `C=$(echo $B | sed 's/%/%%/')`. The result for `ru` is `CgASAnJ1GgA%%3D`
5. Encode `\n\x0bVIDEO_ID\x12\x0e$C` (don't forget to change `VIDEO_ID` to your video id, with `$C` the result of the previous step) with for instance `D=$(printf "\n\x0bVIDEO_ID\x12\x0e$C" | base64)`. The result for `ru` and `lo0X2ZdElQ4` is `CgtsbzBYMlpkRWxRNBIOQ2dBU0FuSjFHZ0ElM0Q=`
6. Use this `params` value from the **Captions in default language** section: `curl -s 'https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/get_transcript?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw "{\"context\":{\"client\":{\"clientName\":\"WEB\",\"clientVersion\":\"2.2021111\"}},\"params\":\"$D\"}"`

Here is a one-line version (do not forget to change `$VIDEO_ID` and `$LANGUAGE_INITIALS`):

```bash
curl -s 'https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/get_transcript?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw "{\"context\":{\"client\":{\"clientName\":\"WEB\",\"clientVersion\":\"2.2021111\"}},\"params\":\"`printf "\n\x0b$VIDEO_ID\x12\x0e\`printf "\n\x00\x12\x02$LANGUAGE_INITIALS\x1a\x00" | base64 -w 0 | jq -sRr @uri | sed 's/%/%%/g'\`" | base64`\"}"
```

Comment: tried the curl command but got an error: 405. That’s an error.

The request method GET is inappropriate for the URL /youtubei/v1/get_transcript. That’s all we know.

Comment: When I wrote it, it used to works, testing again now I have the same result as you but now testing again I don't have the bug anymore even with Tor: `torsocks curl -s 'https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/get_transcript?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8' -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw "{\"context\":{\"client\":{\"clientName\":\"WEB\",\"clientVersion\":\"2.2021111\"}},\"params\":\"$(printf '\n\x0bWdy4YBULvdo' | base64)\"}"` may you confirm ?

Comment: that seems to work. I'll need to figure out how to adapt it to my application. looks like all I have to do is replace it with my key, but not sure where I insert my videoID. is it "x0bWdy4YBULvdo"?

Comment: i get an error when i replace my key with yours: "message": "YouTube Internal API (InnerTube) has not been used in project 914232051599 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtubei.googleapis.com/overview?project=914232051599 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",

Comment: As specified in my original answer the video id I used was "Wdy4YBULvdo" and as specified in my original answer, the key used isn't a YouTube Data API v3 so don't try to change it and if you encounter problem with it in the future check in the original answer how I got it.

Comment: sorry i missed that part when i originally read it.

Comment: I think google wants you to register your website with them and that somehow authorizes the query. unfortunately their documentation is pretty bad and I can't seem to get this to work at all.

Comment: On my side, my shell command is still working. Could you precise the troubles you are facing ? No question of website or registration here as far as I understand what I am doing. And see my `Note:` if the command isn't working because of the key.

Comment: This is so brilliant as it is still working to these days. May I ask, how to you know this trick? Is the API Key is yours?

Comment: It's not a YouTube API key, it's the YouTube UI key. In fact I just used the Network tab from my web-browser and loaded captions on a video and reverse-engineered how the requests were working.

Comment: Does this still work or what I am doing wrong? I get 400 Bad Request with Win10 cmd.   curl -v "https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/get_transcript?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw "{\"context\":{\"client\":{\"clientName\":\"WEB\",\"clientVersion\":\"2.2021111\"}},\"params\":\"CgtsbzBYMlpkRWxRNBIOQ2dBU0FtVnVHZ0ElM0Q=\"}"

Comment: [@John_Sheares](https://stackoverflow.com/users/313978/john-sheares) On Linux Mint 21.1 (curl 7.81.0) I executed the command you shared (without the `-v`) and [got a response with the wanted subtitles](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2510752). I would recommend in fact to use `youtube-dl` or `yt-dlp` for captions retrieving as they propose this feature and are well established softwares.

Comment: Got it working with the Windows cmd line.  Had to format the -H option by changing the single quotes to double quotes.

Comment: Working in Windows Powershell with the following:

$base64 = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("`n`ID HERE"))
$headers = @{
    "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}
$body = @{
    "context" = @{
        "client" = @{
            "clientName" = "WEB"
            "clientVersion" = "2.9999099"
        }
    }
    "params" = $base64
} | ConvertTo-Json

$response = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/get_transcript?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8' -Method Post -Headers $headers -Body $body
Write-Output $response.Content

Comment: This code breaks the response after "webResponseContextExtensionData": '  {
            "hasDecorated": true
        }' and the response doesn't contain the node 'actions' with captions content.

Comment: @Evgeniy Let me investigate that.

Comment: @Evgeniy You are considering *Captions in default language* or *Captions in desired language if available* method with what parameters (video id and language if you are considering the second method)?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison i used https://reqbin.com/curl

Comment: @Evgeniy
For reference you also just commented [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75607675/how-to-get-subtitles-in-any-video-using-youtube-api-v3#comment137728590_75607675).
May you elaborate what you mean by *which breaks the response before the node "actions"*, I do not notice unwanted behavior with *Captions in default language* method, even with https://reqbin.com/curl, note that in this case I paid attention to replace `$(printf '\n\x0bVIDEO_ID' | base64)` with `CgtaaFQ2QmVITm12bw==`.

Comment: 'curl -s 'https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/get_transcript?key=mykey' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw "{\"context\":{\"client\":{\"clientName\":\"WEB\",\"clientVersion\":\"2.9999099\"}},\"params\":\"$(printf '\n\x0bWECQWfbrDRA' | base64)\"}"'gives response, ends with '  "webResponseContextExtensionData": {
            "hasDecorated": true
        }
    },
    "trackingParams": "CAAQw7wCIhMI9uTS9NzihAMVDIDkBh21fQwG"
}'. With Python I get response, where after ''  "webResponseContextExtensionData": {
            "hasDecorated": true' comes  'actions' with captions content.

Comment: I told you to replace `$(printf '\n\x0bWECQWfbrDRA' | base64)` with `CgtXRUNRV2ZickRSQQ==`... When we do so it works perfectly on https://reqbin.com/curl.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that anyone who uses python to try the module youtube_transcript_api. I used to send GET request to [https://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=en&v={videoId}](https://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=en&v=%7BvideoId%7D), but now the page is blank. The following is the code example. In addition, this method does not need api key.

```py
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi
srt = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript("videoId",languages=['en'])
```

Answer (score 2):

The YouTube API change around captions caused me a lot of hassle, which I circumvented through use of [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl), which has [won GitHub legal support](https://github.blog/2020-11-16-standing-up-for-developers-youtube-dl-is-back/) and is now again available for download/clone.

The software is available as source or binary download for all major platforms, details on their GitHub page, linked above.

Sample use is this simple:

```
youtube-dl --write-sub --sub-lang en --skip-download --sub-format vtt https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-lZ8lCG7WY
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a working Python implementation of [the CURL answer provided by Benjamin Loison](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70013529). Replace [`ZhT6BeHNmvo`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhT6BeHNmvo) with your video ID.

```py
import base64
import json
import requests

base64_string = base64.b64encode("\n\vZhT6BeHNmvo".encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8")

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
}

body = json.dumps(
    {
        "context": {"client": {"clientName": "WEB", "clientVersion": "2.9999099"}},
        "params": base64_string,
    }
)

response = requests.post(
    "https://www.youtube.com/youtubei/v1/get_transcript?key=AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8",
    headers=headers,
    data=body,
)

print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Old API currently returns 404 on every request. And YouTube right now uses new version of this API:

[https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v={youtubeVideoId}&asr_langs=de%2Cen%2Ces%2Cfr%2Cid%2Cit%2Cja%2Cko%2Cnl%2Cpt%2Cru%2Ctr%2Cvi&caps=asr&exp=xftt%2Cxctw&xoaf=5&hl=en&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1637102374&sparams=ip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire%2Cv%2Casr_langs%2Ccaps%2Cexp%2Cxoaf&signature=0BEBD68A2638D8A18A5BC78E1851D28300247F93.7D5E6D26397D8E8A93F65CCA97260D090C870462&key=yt8&kind=asr&lang=en&fmt=json3](https://www.youtube.com/api/timedtext?v=%7ByoutubeVideoId%7D&asr_langs=de%2Cen%2Ces%2Cfr%2Cid%2Cit%2Cja%2Cko%2Cnl%2Cpt%2Cru%2Ctr%2Cvi&caps=asr&exp=xftt%2Cxctw&xoaf=5&hl=en&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1637102374&sparams=ip%2Cipbits%2Cexpire%2Cv%2Casr_langs%2Ccaps%2Cexp%2Cxoaf&signature=0BEBD68A2638D8A18A5BC78E1851D28300247F93.7D5E6D26397D8E8A93F65CCA97260D090C870462&key=yt8&kind=asr&lang=en&fmt=json3)

The main problem with this API is to calculate the `signature` field of request. Unfortunately I couldn't find its algorithm. Maybe someone can reverse engineered it from YouTube player.

Comment: that link doesn't work.

Comment: What does the `signature` parameter mean? I see it also has an `expire` parameter, will this URL be used forever?

Comment: it is not possible to get subtitles of many videos. How can you deploy with such a link :)

Comment: @NamLêQuý `signature` is calculated based on all parameters including expire and some secret data which is unknown. `signature` parameter allows backend to validate requests.

Comment: @NamLêQuý This request is used by YouTube itself. Anyone can check it in browser console.

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov I agree. But how can I write the code to get it for my batch of youtube videos? It has non-fixed parameters.

Comment: Notably `signature` is written in the HTML webpage, see [this Git comment](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/yt-dlp/issues/1#issuecomment-1871291302).