# Extracting subtitles from YouTube videos no longer works

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Until today I was using this URL to get captions from YouTube videos:

```
https://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=${lang}&v=${id}
```

For example `https://video.google.com/timedtext?lang=zh&v=rIZNQwCfeig`.

This was always working before, but as of today it started returning a blank response.

Did the API change recently? Is there a new way to get captions from YouTube videos?

Comment: Same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69937867/google-video-no-longer-able-to-retrieve-captions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no signs that this API will get back to life.

I ended up using `youtube-dl` instead:

```sh
youtube-dl --write-sub --sub-lang $LANG_CODE --skip-download --sub-format ttml \
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=$YOUTUBE_ID
```

This will save captions in `ttml` format to a file, you'll need to read its content and delete that file manually. It is a bit more complicated than before, but still much easier than using the official YouTube Captions API.