# Official youtube api to download captions

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there an official youtube api (can be paid) that allows the downloading of videos subtitles (both user and auto generated) even if we're not the owner of the video?
My solution was broken since last youtube api changes (like many others)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70013529/7123660) solve your problem ?

Comment: Thanks for answering Benjamim. I saw this answer before and it works perfectly for now. Keyword: for now.
I'm looking for a stable and official solution so that I'll be sure it will still work tomorrow.

Comment: @RomuloDiniz, probably [Captions: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list) and [Captions: download](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download) are the way to go.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes the Captions: download only work for your own videos (and very few others)