# Adding a CSV Loop to Python Script

Tags: python, loops

I'm sure this is very basic python but I'm tearing my hair out.

I've cobbled together a script that is working for a single input and want to take it to the next level by feeding it a csv of YouTube video IDs to loop through.

I know my code must a mess and I'm mixing use of single and double quotes willy nilly, so any help cleaning up would also be appreciated.

My csv is called 'url.csv' with one column 'url' containing a list of YouTube video IDs.

```
url
1whRd_c_irk
prlK8iY7blk
SnFaRXeep5Y
```

How can I make it so it processes these one by one, essentially replacing the `videoid = "RvCBzhhydNk"` with a loop?

```
import re
import requests
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi

videoid = "RvCBzhhydNk"

#DATE
source = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoid).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, features="html.parser")
published = soup.find("meta", attrs={'itemprop': 'datePublished'})

#VIDEO TITLE and CLEAN-UP
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoid)
title = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', br.title().replace("YouTube", "")).strip()

#TRANSCRIPT
outlines = []
transcript = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript(videoid)
for i in transcript:
        outtext = (i['text'])
        outlines.append(outtext)
        out = outtext.replace(" so ", "\n\nSo ")

#CREATE TEXT FILE
        
        with open((published["content"]) + " " + (title) + ".txt", "a") as opf:
            opf.write(out + " ")
```

Comment: Please update the question with a sample from your csv file

Comment: Put all the code in a `while` loop that reads from the CSV file.

Comment: @Barmar I'm having trouble implementing it because I started using python on friday. I'll look at while loops again tomorrow, thanks.

Comment: Reading a csv file is in the docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader. As happens, your file isn't a CSV file as it only has one field so you can just open it as a file: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll take a look and update with my progress.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. If only I had Googled it sooner. Thanks for the sage advice.

This was inspired by a YouTube transcript scraper I found on Github but had trouble making it work.

I used beatiful soup because I find it much faster than selenium. Removed some features, added some, and finally got it working as desired.

```
filename = 'url.csv'
colname = 'url'
delimiter = '\t'
breakword = 'however'
prefix = 'transcript_'

import re
import csv
import requests
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from youtube_transcript_api import YouTubeTranscriptApi

def gettranscript(videoid):
        try:
        #DATE
                source = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoid).text
                soup = BeautifulSoup(source, features="html.parser")
                published = soup.find("meta", attrs={'itemprop': 'datePublished'})

        #VIDEO TITLE and CLEAN-UP
                br = mechanize.Browser()
                br.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videoid)
                title = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', br.title().replace("YouTube", "")).strip()

        #TRANSCRIPT
                outlines = []
                transcript = YouTubeTranscriptApi.get_transcript(videoid)
                for i in transcript:
                        outtext = (i['text'])
                        outlines.append(outtext)
                        out = outtext.replace(" " + breakword + " ", "\n\n" + breakword + " ")

        #CREATE TEXT FILE
                        with open(prefix + (published["content"]) + " " + (title) + ".txt", "a") as opf:
                            opf.write(out + " ")
        except:
                pass

#READ CSV
csvread = open(filename, newline='\n')
csvreader = csv.DictReader(csvread, delimiter=delimiter, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
rowcount = len(open(filename).readlines())

for row in csvreader:
        msg = gettranscript(row[colname])
```