# How to get subtitles in any video using YouTube API v3?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Could you please help me if I can receive the captions from any YouTube video with captions?
And, if yes, how I can do this?

I'm using this request to get the caption id - https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions?part=id,snippet&videoId=id.

After this, I sent this request https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/captions/captionId

I've added the next scopes:
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner'](https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner%27).

But as a result, I received a 403 error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The permissions associated with the request are not sufficient to download the caption track. The request might not be properly authorized, or the video order might not have enabled third-party contributions for this caption.",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "The permissions associated with the request are not sufficient to download the caption track. The request might not be properly authorized, or the video order might not have enabled third-party contributions for this caption.",
                "domain": "youtube.caption",
                "reason": "forbidden",
                "location": "id",
                "locationType": "parameter"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this Stack Overflow comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30653865/downloading-captions-always-returns-a-403#comment49414961_30660549), I approve this comment. Use [`yt-dlp`](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) to download captions without using YouTube Data API v3.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison The answer you edited, https://stackoverflow.com/a/76377150/1992004, works for me - but not its curl ancestor, which breaks the response before the node "actions", which in fact contains the captions content.

Comment: Let me investigate that.

Comment: For reference you also just commented [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69937867/google-video-no-longer-able-to-retrieve-captions/70013529#comment137728563_70013529).