# YouTube captions download incorrect format

Tags: .net-core, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I using YouTube Data API to download captions and it seems to work but when I download the subtitles from api the content is not in the correct format.

```
1
00:00:00,719 --> 00:00:06,000
{LONG TEXT CONTAINS ALL SCRIPT}

2
00:00:03,240 --> 00:00:09,120

3
00:00:06,000 --> 00:00:11,219
[REST OF THE TIME WITH EMPTY LINES]
```

However, it looks correct when I download using studio.youtube.com.

Is there a fix for that?

PS: [Google](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support) says I must use stackoverflow with tags but so far I cannot get any answers or comments. Is it now correct approach?

EDIT:

Based on the [API document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/download) I am using below code and it downloads the subtitle but not with correctly formated data.

```js
YouTubeService youtubeService = await GetYouTubeService();

// Get the list of available captions for the video
var captionListRequest = youtubeService.Captions.List("snippet, id", book.BSYouTubeId);

var captionListResponse = await captionListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

// Get the first caption track
var captionTrack = captionListResponse.Items.FirstOrDefault();
if (captionTrack == null)
{
    context.WriteLine("No caption track found.");
    return;
}

// Download the caption track
var captionDownloadRequest = youtubeService.Captions.Download(captionTrack.Id);
captionDownloadRequest.Tfmt = "srt";
captionDownloadRequest.Tlang = book.GetShortLanguageCode();
var captionStream = await captionDownloadRequest.ExecuteAsStreamAsync();

// Read the caption track into a string
var captionString = new StreamReader(captionStream).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on *I use YouTube Data API to download captions*? Maybe the problem comes from how you proceed.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems to be a YouTube Data API v3 issue, I recommend you to use [`yt-dlp`](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp) by using:

```bash
yt-dlp --write-sub --sub-lang all,-live_chat 'VIDEO_ID'
```

Comment: thanks for the reply I forgot to mention it is .net 7.

Comment: but I agree with that with youtube API it seems like nothing working correctly.

Comment: I don't see any .net solution except re-implementing yt-dlp captions extraction which is quite out of scope.

Comment: Is not yt-dpl using the api? Can point me to the source code that handles subtitle downloads? I m using Google .Net library so it should work out of the box.

Comment: `yt-dlp` doesn't use YouTube Data API v3, if you're interested in a quite simple approach consider [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70013529).