# youtubei: How to get available transcripts of a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm making an Android app that would fetch the transcripts of a video. The user can specified which language to fetch. Here I assume the videoID is given.

Is there any way to achieve this by using YouTube's internal API youtubei?
I could not find anywhere a documentation of this API, eventhough there seems to be alot of usage of this API out there. So I'd really appreciate if someone can share any source of information of how to use this API.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69937867/google-video-no-longer-able-to-retrieve-captions/70013529#70013529), Benjamin has given a good solution to get the transcript of a video for a given language, but then you need to know if there even exists a transcript for that language. So I would like to know if somehow I can get a list of available languages of the video.
Then I can implement like this.

1. Get available languages of the video.
2. Check that they have the user's requested language
3. Get the transcript

Comment: I recommend using `yt-dlp` for such transcripts retrieval.

Comment: It's in python though, though maybe there's a way to use it from Java. But in case I don't want to use yt-dlp, is there really no way to achieve this using youtubei ?